# RichTextbox in HTML file

Tags: php, html, mysql, textbox

i want to put a richtextboc in my form.html file because i need to write code with style and "
" on it, how can i do it? thank you
i tried tu download some scriptthat i found on the net , as the  ckeditor but idk how to let it work..

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/stile.css">
    <title>tabella</title>
</head>

<body>
    <br>
    <div class="titlebarpesiti" style="background-color:#22AEB9">
    CONTROLLO SITO
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="titlebarpesiti">
        <form id="richiesta dati" name="richiesta dati" method="POST" action="PHP/Scrittura_dati.php">

            <label for="festa">Festa: &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="festa"> <br> <br>
            <label for="data">Data: &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="data"><br> <br> 
            <label for="luogo">Luogo: &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="luogo"><br> <br>
            <label for="prezzo">Prezzo: &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="prezzo"><br> <br>
            <label for="bus">Bus: &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="bus"><br> <br>
            <label for="organizzatori">Organizzatori: &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="organizzatore"><br> <br>
            <label for="dettagli">Altre info: &nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="dettagli"><br> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Invia Dati"><br> </br>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="titlebarpesiti" style="background-color:#FF0004">
    ELIMINARE DATI
        <form id="eliminare dati" name="eliminare dati" method="POST" action="PHP/eliminaredati.php">
            <input type="text" name="ideliminare">
            <input type="submit" value="INVIO"><br> </br>
        </form>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: html does not have rich edit controls, you have to use some 3rd party libraries like fckedit, tinemce, if you cannot understand how to use them - RTFM finally

Answer (score 0):

Use TinyMCE, http://www.tinymce.com/

It has plenty of languages.